Linear Algebra Done Right 4th edition 7A Exercise 27 on normal operator
Suppose $V$ is a nonzero finite-dimensional inner product space over $\mathbb{F}$, where $\mathbb{F}$ deonotes either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.
Let $T$ be a normal operator on $V$. For every positive integer $k$, I want to show that

$\text{null}(T^{k}) = \text{null}(T)$

$\text{range}(T^{k}) = \text{range}(T)$


I know it is sufficient to show that $\text{null}(T^{2}) = \text{null}(T)$ for 1., and $\text{range}(T^{2}) = \text{range}(T)$ for 2. I also know that as $T$'s power gets larger, the null space remains the same or gets bigger, and the range remains the same or gets smaller.
So with 1., I only need to show $\text{null}(T^{2}) \subseteq \text{null}(T)$, I try with $$TTv = 0 \implies T^{*}Tv = 0 \implies TT^{*}v = 0 \implies Tv, T^{*}v \in \text{null}(T) $$
but I don't know what the next step is to show that $v\in \text{null}(T)$, or actually if this is the way.
With 2., I only need to show that range $T \subseteq \text{range} (T^{2})$, but I can't find a first step to show that if $v = Tu$ for some $u \in V$, then $v = T^{2}w$ for some $w \in V$. I may need a hint.

For 1:
$$
T T v = 0 \implies T^* T v = 0 \implies \langle T^* T v, v \rangle = 0 \implies \langle T v, T v \rangle = 0 \implies T v = 0.
$$
Now use 1 to prove 2:
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\range}{range}
\DeclareMathOperator{\null}{null}
\range T^k = (\null (T^k)^*)^\perp = (\null (T^*)^k)^\perp = (\null T^*)^\perp = \range T.
$$
